# Resetting file security to inherit AFTER a MoveFile() operation

Tags: c++, windows, security

Windows/C++

Looking for some recommendations on how to reset the security attributes on a file after it's been moved to a new folder.

Our standard way of creating files (and download from the server) is to create the file in a temporary folder, then as the file streams down, the file is appended.  Once the download is completed, we move the file to it's final destination.

MoveFile() will transfer the security on the file when the file is moved.  In certain configuration this causes a problem -- where the security defaults of final folder don't match the original folder.   We cannot mess with folder security....

So, ultimately, I would like to perform an operation on the file after I move it.  My current thinking is that I should fetch the security attributes of the folder it goes into, and then apply to the file after the move is completed.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Harry's answer, here is the full code:

```
// blank acl used to restore permissions after a file move
ACL g_null_acl = { 0 };
InitializeAcl(&g_null_acl, sizeof(g_null_acl), ACL_REVISION);

DWORD error = SetNamedSecurityInfo(file_path, SE_FILE_OBJECT,
    DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
    NULL, NULL, (PACL)&g_null_acl, NULL);
```

Keep in mind that calling [`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579.aspx) (in this instance) requires `SE_RESTORE_NAME` privileges, so it cannot be called from a service running as Network Service (or Local Service), as they have [limited permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272.aspx).

Comment: `SE_SECURITY_NAME` is only required if you are changing the SACL.  In this case we are only changing the DACL so it is not needed.  However, you will need either the appropriate file-level permissions, or `SE_RESTORE_NAME`.

Comment: It may be worth noting that when used this way `::SetNamedSecurityInfo` does not return ERROR_SUCCESS. It seems to always return 1008 (0x3f0): "An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.". It still seems to work fine. (This was tested on Win 7 SP1 x64.)

Comment: @PatrickW: behaves as expected for me, i.e., returns ERROR_SUCCESS.  I'm also on Win 7 SP1 x64.  Perhaps you were trying to use it in an invalid context, e.g., while impersonating at SecurityIdentification level?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` flag.  Just pass an empty ACL to remove the entries the file got from its previous parent.  This would look something like this:

```
error = SetNamedSecurityInfo(
            path_to_file, 
            SE_FILE_OBJECT, 
            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            empty_acl, 
            NULL);
```